# iOS Filter NSFetchedResultsController Efficiently

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, core-data, ipod-touch

I'm attempting to add search support to a **Core Data** backed `UITableView` and started to hit some performance issues. I currently have associations to two `NSFetchedResultsController` (one for regular and one for searching). In my `UISearchDisplayDelegate` methods I release and recreate my `NSFetchedResultsController` after each call. However, this causes lag while typing! Is there a more efficient way to filter an `NSFetchedResultsController`? I've setup my batch size to around 50 items and my database has a few thousand records if that makes a difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`NSFetchedResultsController` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/) makes it pretty clear:

- If there is a cache, delete it.
- Update the `fetchRequest` property. Note that you cannot simply modify the existing fetch request; you must create a new one.
- Call `-executeFetch:`.

Comment: Is this a more efficient than recreating an `NSFetchedResultsController` given that a new call to execute fetch is given each time?

Comment: At the very least, you don’t have the overhead of creating and destroying an `NSFetchedResultsController` each time. So, while I don’t have any metrics of how *much* more efficient it is, it ought to be.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try but it looks like I might have to add some async code (and delay the fetch) to really fix this!

Answer (score 3):

I use the following code to filter the results of the FetchedResultController

```
NSPredicate *pre = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute CONTAINS [cd] %@", searchString];
NSArray *searchResults = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pre]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This approach cannot be used when `UITableView` has to be updated row by row.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

Create the NSFetchRequest instance and change its sort descriptor each time:

```
 let shortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: key, ascending: ascending)
    request.sortDescriptors = [shortDescriptor]

    do {
        try fetchedResultViewController?.performFetch()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error in fetch \(error)")
    }
```

Read the apple document: https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller