# Modify NSFetchedResultsController fetchRequest in iOS 7

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I found this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4861732/1486928

I'm trying to do that but it won't let me assign a newly created `NSFetchRequest` and in the documentation it says :

> @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest

But in the next line it says :

> Special Considerations : If you want to modify the fetch request, you must follow the steps described in “The Fetch Request.”

So which is it, am I allowed to modify it or not :/ ? Very confusing that the property is `readonly` and they say we can modify it :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `fetchRequest` is a read-only property

```
open var fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ResultType> { get }
```

But the `NSFetchRequest` **instance is a mutable** property so you can change its entity / sort descriptor / predicate / ...

Comment: Oh ok so I souldn't create a new one but rather modify the fetchrequest properties ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

Create the NSFetchRequest instance and change its sort descriptor each time:

```
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: key, ascending: ascending)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    do {
        try fetchedResultViewController?.performFetch()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error in fetch \(error)")
    }
```

Read the apple document: https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller